Rank of the derivative of g with $ \|g(x)\|=1 $
Let $ G\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ be a bounded region and
$$ g:G\to \mathbb{R}^n $$
differentiable with
$$ \|g(x)\|=1 $$
for all $ x\in G $.
Is then
$$ \det(Dg(x))=0 $$
for all $ x\in G $? And if so: Why?

This is true.
Differentiate $\langle g(x), g(x) \rangle = 1$ to get
$$Dg(x)^T g(x) = 0$$
for all $x \in G$. Since $\|g(x)\| = 1$, we see that $g(x)$ is not the zero vector. Hence $Dg(x)^T$ has a nonzero singular vector, and thus have det 0.

Thank you! That helped me a lot just using $|g(x)|^2 = \langle g(x),g(x)\rangle = g(x)^T g(x) $ to differentiate.
